# Twitter API: How to get recent tweets from the users the owner of the profile follows

Tags: ios4, twitter

my question may seem a bit complicated but let me clarify. Using Twitter's Api system, I was able to get the 20 most recent tweets of a particular user. However, this isn't really exactly what I wanted. As I am making an iPhone application, it would seem more interesting for the user to see the most recent tweets from other people he follows than tweets he himself has composed. So, is there anyway to get the 20 most recent tweets from users that a particular person follows? If the question is not clear enough please let me know so I can clarify it, thanks :)

Comment: Did you take a look at this?  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/ids

Comment: A particular user or all of his followers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get up to 800 tweets from the user's followers

[https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/home_timeline)

For example, if you want 20 tweets, but no replies, use

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json?count=20&exclude_replies=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the ids of the followers
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/ids
Should be something like...
 /followers/ids.json?screen_name=xxx 
or possibly /followers/ids.json?user_id=xxx

Then, get the tweets from those ids
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=20